# Causal Diagram and multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression, causality, bayesian-network, causal-diagram

I have 4 nodes:

A causes B and C, and C by itself causes D. However, C is not measurable, and my interest is to test the association between B and D. What would be the right causal diagram and multiple regression expression?

My guess is `lm(D ~ B + A)`, because conditioning on A can remove the association between B and C, and therefore the estimated $\hat \beta_{B}$ reflects the realistic $\beta_B$, which is 0. Is my interpretation correct?

[image]

Comment: What is meant by "test the association between B and D"? Do you want to to know the correlation between B and D? Or do you want to know the causal association where you already know the direction is going from B to D and you just want to know the effect size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. Conditioning on $A$ blocks the backdoor path $B\leftarrow A\to C\to D.$ Since $C$ is unavailable because it is unmeasured, you must condition on $A$ to block the backdoor path. Including $A$ on the RHS of your linear regression model is probably the most straight-forward way to condition on it. So I'd say your model, assuming it is correct, should provide the unbiased effect of $B$ on $D.$